# Flask - Post a file with accompying JSON

Tags: python, post, flask

Is it possible to POST a file to a flask app that has both a file and JSON data accompanying it?

In my initial development, I am doing this via two api endpoints, and it just seems clunky. I'd like to be able to accomplish this using one POST, instead of two.

Is this possible?

Comment: you need to make a multipart request

Comment: Just make a multipart POST request; one of the parts is your file upload, the other parts can either be a JSON-encoded string or include separate key/values like you would in a regular form POST.

Comment: That worked, thanks! Guess I still have a bit of learning to do about all of this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can POST a file with JSON data accompanying it. For example:

```
import requests
with open(path_to_file, 'rb') as my_file:
        files = {'file': my_file}
        payload = {'data1': 'foo', 'data2': 'bar'}
        r = requests.post(data=payload, files=files)
```

There is a lot of useful information regarding Flask and requests (a very nice HTTP lib) here:

1. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#quickstart
2. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/

Comment: This solution will only work if each of the arguments in `payload` is a string, so it's not really a JSON object you are sending. And if all of the arguments are strings, you might as well include them in the `files` object.